# Shared context during object deserialization

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using GSON for deserializing some JSON data and I'm interested in a way to pass some contextual values into the deserialization process. To be more specific, suppose we have 2 classes:

```
class A {
   String relativePath;
   transient B contextDependentValue;
}

class B {
   int y;
   A z;
}
```

and a JSON as follows:

```
{
  y: 2,
  z: {
    relativePath: "./foo/bar"
  }
}
```

When trying to deserialize things, I'd like to populate the `contextDependentValue` field in the nested object with something that is dependent on where the context of deserialization (e.g. `contextDependentValue` could be the absolute path on which the JSON was found, so I could then build the full path as `contextDependentValue + '/' + relativePath`). These context values would be set **for each deserialization**.

Ideally, I would be able to build a custom `JsonDeserializer` that gets a context values holder when asked to deserialize:

```
public T deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, 
     JsonDeserializationContext context, 
     Map<String, Object> someSortOfContextValuesHolder) {

   return buildObjectWithContext(json, someSortOfContextValuesHolder);
}
```

and where `someSortOfContextValuesHolder` would be provided when starting each deserialization:

```
gson.fromJson(json, B.class, someSortOfContextValuesHolder)
```

Any ideas on how I could implement something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Gson's TypeAdaptor](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html)

> By default Gson converts application classes to JSON using its built-in type adapters. If Gson's default JSON conversion isn't appropriate for a type, extend this class to customize the conversion.

This stackoverflow article about [how-to-handle-deserializing-with-polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736654/how-to-handle-deserializing-with-polymorphism) also shows sample code samples which may prove relevant and help you out a bit.

Should you be interested in marshalling at runtime you should look into [RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java)

> Adapts values whose runtime type may differ from their declaration type.

...and these article about [convert-from-json-to-multiple-unknown-java-object-types-using-gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049684/convert-from-json-to-multiple-unknown-java-object-types-using-gson) and [how-to-deserialize-a-list-of-polymorphic-objects-with-gson](https://futurestud.io/blog/how-to-deserialize-a-list-of-polymorphic-objects-with-gson/) might also prove useful.

Comment: The problem with the TypeAdaptor and the JsonDeserializer are that they are set once and work for __all__ the deserialization. I am more interested in a way to customize that adaptor at each call, taking into account that it could work on multiple threads.

Comment: I've updated my original answer with details around Gson support for runtime type based marshalling, let me know if those are helpful...